# rails form: don't show child in form, if already has this child

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Person.rb:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :skills
end
```

Skill.rb:

```
   class Skill < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :person
      validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :person_id
    end
```

I made skills nested in Routes.rb:

```
  resources :people do 
    resources :skills
    end
  end
```

Now, when creating a new skill for the client in `clients/1/skills/new` I do not want to be able to select a skill that the client already has. How can it be done? Here is my current input field:

```
= f.select :skill_id, Skill.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, {include_blank: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which Rails version you're running, but you could make a scope for the `Skill` class.

```
 scope :remaining, ->(name) { where.not(name: name) }
```

Then update your view:

```
 = f.select :skill_id, Skill.remaining(@person.skills.map(&:name)).map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, { include_blank: true }
```

That's untested, not sure if you'd need to `.map` the `:name` but you get the idea. Also change `:name` to `:id` if that suits better for your use case (I'm not sure if you enforce skill uniqueness across the board or just per-user).

It looks a little clunky for your view, though, so you could throw it onto the `Skill` class assuming you have the right columns.

```
def self.remaining # you're mapping the skill, not the client
  where.not(id: person.skill_ids).map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }
end
```

Then the view'd just be:

```
= f.select :skill_id, Skill.remaining, { include_blank: true }
```

As an aside, I'm going to guess the `/clients` versus `/people` are the same thing with different names only on SO, otherwise that's going to cause headaches and/or break.

Answer (score 0):

in person.rb

```
def available_skills 
   skills = self.skills.pluck(:name, :id)
   Skill.pluck(:name, :id).select{|s| !skills.include?(s)}
end
```

in view template:

```
<%= f.select :skill_id, @person.available_skills, {include_blank: true} %>
```